# how to trigger a message in header section of webpage after perform an action in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm new to the PHP and Wordpress. I don't know much more about plugin development.

What action would I have to perform if I wanted to display a message in header page after post a comment?

The message or id displaying while checking through the `wp_die`, but I have to show it in header page. Can anyone please help me?

The sample code as below:

```
function disp($comment_ID)
{
    echo $comment_ID;
}

function commenttrigger_message($comment_ID, $comment_approved )
{
    disp($comment_ID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an action named `comment_post`, which is triggered when comment is inserted into DB.

You can integrate any call back function with `comment_post` action which you want to invoke after posting a comment.

```
add_action('comment_post', 'show_message_function');

function show_message_function($comment_ID, $comment_approved) 
{
   //function logic goes here
}
```

Comment: I used 'comment_post' action only.I just want to know how to trigger a message in header page after post a comment.I can show the message by using wp_die but that is not visible in header page